# Delphi XE3, Indy TCP Server. Shut down server

Tags: delphi, indy

I have adapted the following code from another post on this website, but it still seems to freeze.  I must be able to turn off or disconnect the server even if there are clients connected.  I will wait till they finish sending messages but if I start the server, connect to it from a client, I still can't shut down the server without freezing.  I then have to shut off with Windows Task Manager.

```
procedure TTasksForm.ShutDownPantherServer;
var i : integer ;
    Context: TidContext;
begin

  if PantherIdTCPServer.Active = True then
    with PantherIdTCPServer.Contexts.LockList do
    try

      for i := (PantherIdTCPServer.Contexts.LockList.Count - 1) downto 0 do
      begin

        Context := Items[i] ;

        if Context = nil then
          Continue;
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClear;
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.Close;

        if Context.Connection.Connected then
          Context.Connection.Disconnect;

      end;

    finally
      PantherIdTCPServer.Contexts.UnLockList ;
    end ;

  if PantherIdTCPServer.Active = True then
    PantherIdTCPServer.Active := False ;

end;
```

Additonal information...

I use the following code to connect to the server. When it connects the server sends back a message that there was a connection.

Client Connect To Server

```
procedure TPantherSimulatorForm.ConnectToServer ;
var MsgIn : String ;
begin

  PantherIdTCPClient.Host := IPAddressEdit.Text ;
  PantherIdTCPClient.Port := StrToInt(PortEdit.Text) ;

  PantherIdTCPClient.Connect;

  MsgIn := PantherIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();

  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin

      ClientTrafficMemo.Clear ;
      ClientTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime( 'yyyy-mm-dd    hh:nn:ss.zzz', now ) +
'  ' + MsgIn) ;
    end ) ;

end;
```

OnConnect on server

```
procedure TTasksForm.PantherIdTCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := Indy8BitEncoding ;

  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime( 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now ) +
'  OnConnect') ;
end );

  // connected message
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Connected');

end;
```

The combination of these 2 procedures will cause the server to freeze when I attempt to close the server program if I do not shut down the client first. I apologize I am too new to Indy to see what the issue is or how to do the thread work to solve the problem. I was hoping you would see my beginners error in one of the 2 connection procedures.

Here is the OnExecute code:

```
procedure TForm2.PantherIdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Sleep(1000) ;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
        ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime( 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now ) +
'  OnExecute') ;
    end ) ;

end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `with` statement is calling `Contexts.LockList()` and then your loop is calling `Contexts.LockList()` again, but you are only calling `Contexts.UnlockList()` once after the loop has completed.  As such, the `Contexts` list is still locked, and any further access by any other threads will deadlock indefinitely, including the client threads when they try to remove themselves from the `Contexts` list, which in turn will deadlock the `Active` property setter since it waits for all of the client thread to terminate.

In your loop, replace `PantherIdTCPServer.Contexts.LockList.Count` with simply `Count` since the `with` is acting on the `TList` that `LockList()` returned:

```
procedure TTasksForm.ShutDownPantherServer;
var
  i : integer ;
  Context: TidContext;
begin
  if PantherIdTCPServer.Active = True then
    with PantherIdTCPServer.Contexts.LockList do
    try
      // HERE!!!
      for i := ({PantherIdTCPServer.Contexts.LockList.}Count - 1) downto 0 do
      begin

        Context := Items[i] ;

        if Context = nil then
          Continue;
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClear;
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.Close;

        if Context.Connection.Connected then
          Context.Connection.Disconnect;

      end;

    finally
      PantherIdTCPServer.Contexts.UnLockList ;
    end ;

  if PantherIdTCPServer.Active = True then
    PantherIdTCPServer.Active := False ;

end;
```

In fact, all of the code you have show is completely redundant and should be removed, this is all you need:

```
procedure TTasksForm.ShutDownPantherServer;
begin
  PantherIdTCPServer.Active := False;
end;
```

It already does all of the hard work of disconnecting active clients, clearing the `Contexts` list, and shutting down the server.  You don't need to do that stuff manually at all.

Comment: I had already tried that based on another post of yours but if a client has already connected to the server and if I do PantherIdTCPServer.Active := False then I try to close the form the program freezes and won't close.  If shut down the client program that was connected then shut down the server I can close the form with no freezing.  If the client has connected and is still connected and I shut down the server and close the form it freezes.  I do not have OnClose or OnCloseQuery events on the server program.  It seems it freezes until I disconnect the client from the client.

Comment: You have a deadlock issue, such as if you are deactivating the server from the main thread while the client does something that syncs with the main thread. The client will be blocked waiting on the main thread, and the main thread will be blocked waiting on the client. The code you showed in your question suffers from that same problem. So either do not sync with the main thread while deactivating the server in the main thread, or else deactivate the server from a separate worker thread so the main thread is not blocked.

Comment: if I am only assigning one client per server, since the client is a medical device running on a workstation, is sychronizing an issue.  Just curious?

Comment: Yes, it is an issue. `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component, each listening port runs in its own thread, and each connected client runs in its own thread. Each one client requires proper synchronizing if it needs to access things in other threads, including the main thread.

Comment: I have added a ShowMessage to the OnExecute procedure on the server. That is all the OnExecute does now.  As soon as the client connects to the server the OnExecute event on the server starts.  When I click on the ShowMessage window button the ShowMessage immediately shows up showing the OnExecute procedure is run over and over whether the client is sending something to the server or not.  As soon as I close the client program it stops.  I thought the OnExecute only ran when a message was sent to the server(?)

Comment: ShowMessage() displays a VCL form, and as such is not thread-safe and must not be called outside of the main UI thread. In any case, no, the OnExecute event does not fire when data arrives. It indeed runs in an endless loop while the client is connected. It is your responsibility to decide what to do when OnExecute fires. The *typical* usage is to block the calling thread waiting for an incoming message, process it, and then exit, and let the next loop iteration wait for the next message.

Comment: I only added the ShowMessage to see what was happening in the server when the client connecterd.  It is inside a thread synchronize procedure.  What can I do so I can IdTCPServer.Active := False without freeziing the server.  I have not been able to figure out how to shut down the server and close the form without it freezing.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the client program to disconnect.

Comment: The **only** way it can freeze during deactivation is if you are deadlocking the server threads in your own code so they cannot terminate correctly. Suh as syncing with the main thread while it is busy deactivating the server. You are responsible for writing thread-safe event handler code. If you are having problems doing that, please edit your question to include your OnExecute code. The only *potential* deadlock in the code you have shown so far is the sync in OnConnect. Try using `TThread.Queue()` instead, which is not blocking.

Comment: Deactivating the server automatically disconnects any connected client. The clients will raise an exception, like `EIdConnClosedGracefully`, the next time they access their socket connection. If you want to be more explicit about it, you could have your server code send a command to each client before deactivating the server, and then have the client recognize the command and disconnect themselves.

Comment: I have added the server OnExecute and the client's OnConnect code to show what the complete code.  This code is only temporary to test telling the server Active := False

Comment: You have not shown your server OnExecute code, or updated the code shown to make any of the changes I suggested.

Comment: I have listed my OnExecute code near the bottom of the original listing.  I am using TThread.Queue() as you suggested.  My problem is i don't know why one the client connects I can't tell the server Active := False without the program stopping responding.  Is there sample code of a tcpserver app and tcp client code where the server can chasnge Active to false and close the form without freezing.   My code seems very simple but it definately freezes when I change Active to false and try to close the form.

Comment: There is NO OnExecute code shown yet. I see client code. I see server OnConnect code. I do NOT see server OnExecute code. Since I cannot see ALL of your server code, I cannot tell you *for sure* WHY the server is freezing. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing ALL of your *latest* code.

Comment: Here is the OnExecute procedure listed above.  I don't know why it is not visible to you(?).   I am using a different server program  to test Active := False.          procedure TForm2.PantherIdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin

  Sleep(1000) ;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin


      ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime( 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now ) +
    '  OnExecute') ;



    end ) ;

end;

Comment: Is it imprper for me to ask Remy Lebeau if his company does paid consulting?

Comment: I moved the code into the question where it belongs. I see nothing that should be deadlocking, unless it is frozen on the `TThread.Synchronize()` in `OnConnect`. Try changing that to `TThread.Queue()` instead. Is there any `OnDisconnect` code you have not shown yet? Any blockage of that event can also freeze deactivation.

Comment: Adding the TThread.Queue to all the events seems to have solved the problem on the "test" server program.  I will check it out on the actual server program.  Remy, thank you for your patience.  I am still interested if your company does paid consulting.

Comment: A link to my website is in [my StackOverflow profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau?tab=profile).